# Mandelbrot Set not displaying at center

Tags: c++, fractals

I think the problem is how I'm converting the Cartesian coordinate into a Complex number but I have now idea how. Can you please explain how should I convert? Here's what I tried though:

```
double c_Im = (y + (maxIm - minIm)) / height;
double c_Re = (x + (maxRe - minRe)) / width;
```

Code:

```
float minRe = -2.0;
float maxRe = 2.0;
double minIm = -2.0;
double maxIm = 2.0;

for (size_t y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        double c_Im = (y + (maxIm - minIm)) / height;

        for (size_t x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            double c_Re = (x + (maxRe - minRe)) / width;
            float dx = 0, dy = 0;
            int z = 0;
            while (dx * dx + dy * dy < 4 && z < maxIterator)
            {
                float temp = (dx * dx - dy * dy) + c_Re;
                dy = 2 * dx * dy + c_Im;
                dx = temp;
                z++;
            }
            image.setPixel(x, y, Color(z % 255, z % 255, z % 255));

        }
    }
```

not_expected_output.jpg
[image: not expected output]

Comment: I think it's your coordinate system. I think your window is not mapped -1 to 1 but rather (0,0) to (width, height)

Comment: How should I map it? can you please explain?

Comment: Your minimum value for both the real and imaginary parts should be 0 when you map it to the window, and the maximum values should be the window width and the window height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the formula you're looking for is this:

`double c_Im = y * (maxIm - minIm) / height + minIm;`

`double c_Re = x * (maxRe - minRe) / width + minRe;`

This is derived from the map formula: Y=(X-A)*(D-C)/(B-A)+C